# How to use the concept of corporate account in MembershipReboot

Tags: thinktecture-ident-server, identity-management, membershipreboot

I'm studying [MembershipReboot](https://github.com/brockallen/BrockAllen.MembershipReboot) for a professional corporate solutions.
The background is:

- There are companies
- A company has one or more users administrators / owners
- User administrator adds users with role administrator, worker

In the multitenant meaning...

1. Could **user group** be used as company?
2. is Each user a tenant?
3. Could be a role per company and user / tenant assigned?

Comment: I don't think there is a need for user group be used as a company. MembershipReboot has a concept of tenant which, in my opinion, represents company in your case.
In that case user is not a tenant. You assign (create) users to tenant company. Regarding question 3 - I don't quite understand what are you asking.

Comment: @ZeljkoVujaklija ex. user 1 has 'Company1.CalendarsRead', 'Company2.CalendarsWrite' and user 2 has 'Company1.CalendarsWrite'